# Import ASCII (X, Y, Value) to Feature Attribute in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, ascii

The output from my landscaping modeling program is simply way too big to be rendered by  Paraview. So I am wondering is there anyway that I can import it into ArcMap. The data is divided into several files, with one .nodeinfo file which contains x-y coordinates and other files contain data but in the same order. I can re-arrange them into a |x|y|value| format from Matlab, but I don't know how can I import this into ArcMap.

This is just like the reverse version of "Export Feature Attribute to ASCII" function in ArcMap.

Answer (score 4):

add the data as txt or csv.
then right click and "display xy"

Answer (score 1):

You can Format you data as CSV file then import them through [Qgis](http://www.qgis.org/fr/site/forusers/download.html), then export layer as Shapefile using `Save as a SHAPEFILE`, then add the shapefile to Arcmap.

Comment: you can do the same in arcmap

Answer (score 1):

If you have Line or Polygon data, ArcMap Add XY Data will not work. However, there is a free tool from ESRI, Create Features From Text File. [sample tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geoprocessing-Model-and-Script-Tool-Gallery/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9). You can find the text file formatting online, search ArcGIS 9.2 help.

Answer (score 1):

This [topic](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27589) explain table formats that ArcMap can read.

[image]